# Disable capture keys when program is unresponsive

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application that can get pretty unresponsive during heavy calculations. For example, when user presses `F10` key, the program will starts some heavy stuff and remains unrsponsive for a while (I know this is not a desired way of program flow but I don't want to alter the way program works at the moment).

Now the problem is, during this time if user presses `F10` again, the program will start doing the same thing as soon as it has done the first process.

How to disable capturing keys at a certain point and enable it again?

Comment: You should fix the real problem (the temporary becomes permanent) and put the calculations in a apbackgrounf thread. It should be really easy using the Task parallel library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Is it really expensive to move calculations to BackgroundWorker and just disable the form before completition callback will be raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is not "capturing the key", it is queued by the operating system because your main UI-Thread is busy with your calculations and doesn't handle anything at that time. The only thing i could think of what you could do is to check that a certain time has elapsed after the last run has finished before you allow another run. An ugly hack in my humble opinion.

But, yeah, thats why you should use backgroundworkers or threading. Using a BackgroundWorker is a lot easier than it may seem at the beginning.

Comment: Exactly for these reasons the Threading is created. Make some research and eliminate the problem at the core. Otherwise you'll end up with a stack of stubs that must be corrected. In Project Management it is called "Infinite Defect Strategy"

Comment: Using a timer is never a good option - what happens if your CPU is under load and the calculations take a fraction longer than your timer is set for - now your back to square one.  Say you compensate for this scenario and increase your timer, your CPU is under normal load and now your calcualtions have finished and you're now waiting for your timer to free up the UI.  Not a good solution from any point of view.

Comment: Where did i recommend the use of a timer? I would just store the current microseconds in a variable _lastRunMicroSeconds right after my long-running process finished and not allow a subsequent run until currentMicroSeconds > (_lastRunMicroSeconds + bufferMicroSeconds) where the size of the buffer would have to be determined. I also didn't say that it's a good solution. :)

Comment: OK - in fairness, you didn't say it was a good option.  Should have taken more notice of the "ugly hack" part!  :)  My point was more that it could introduce as many problems as it solved.  Apologies for overkill!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use a `BackgroundWorker` here but as you said

> I don't want to alter the way program works at the moment).

So I won't go into that path.

What you can do is when you detect F-10 for the first time set a bool value to true and next time whenever you detect f-10, check if the bool is already true or not. If it is already true don't start the heavy operation again simply skip the code.

At the end of heavy processing set the bool to false again.

Comment: This will fail because the heavy work on the ui-thread will be finished and the bool will be reverted to true when the keypress event reaches the program.

Comment: I don't think the bool will fix anything, as the second heavy process starts as soon as the first ends.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Jason on the whole - hacks and temporary fixes have a nasty habit of becoming 'features' of a program.

However, to answer your question, I would suggest having a disable flag in your program that disables the desired functionality whilst your calculations are running.  You could then put in the event handler a check for the flag :

```
public bool DisableFlag { get; set; }

public void MyKeyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DisableFlag)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff
}
```

Hope that helps!
Cheers,
Chris.

EDIT :

Thinking about Ken's comment, and this is true, the event will be queued and it will only be useful as long as some events are bleeding through.  So, the other option is to disable the even handler altogether by doing

```
myControl =- MyKeyEventHandler;
```

and then

```
myControl =+ MyKeyEventHandler;
```

when the calculations are finished.  This way, no events are queued and you avoid the problem as described by Ken!!

Comment: I don't think it'll fix anything as the KeyPress messages will be processed after the end of the heavy process. As you'll have to enable your flag after the end of the process, the problem will remains.